# Can i fetch all from Google translation API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-translation-api

I have this function in my main component in my react app:

```
componentDidMount(){
        const land = ["Afrikaans", "Albanian", "Amharic", "Arabic", "Armenian", "Assamese", "Aymara", "Azerbaijani", "Bambara", "Basque", "Belarusian", "Bengali", "Bhojpuri", "Bosnian",
        "Bulgarian", "Catalan", "Cebuano", "Chinese (Simplified)", "Chinese (Traditional)", "Corsican", "Croatian", "Czech", "Danish", "Dhivehi", "Dogri", "Dutch", "English", "Esperanto",
        "Estonian", "Ewe", "Filipino (Tagalog)", "Finnish", "French", "Frisian", "Galician", "Georgian", "German", "Greek", "Guarani", "Gujarati", "Haitian Creole", "Hausa", "Hawaiian",
        "Hebrew", "Hindi", "Hmong", "Hungarian", "Icelandic", "Igbo", "Ilocano", "Indonesian", "Irish", "Italian", "Japanese", "Javanese", "Kannada", "Kazakh", "Khmer", "Kinyarwanda",            
        "Konkani", "Korean", "Krio", "Kurdish", "Kurdish (Sorani)", "Kyrgyz", "Lao", "Latin", "Latvian", "Lingala", "Lithuanian", "Luganda", "Luxembourgish", "Macedonian", "Maithili", "Malagasy",
        "Malay", "Malayalam", "Maltese", "Maori", "Marathi", "Meiteilon (Manipuri)", "Mizo", "Mongolian", "Myanmar (Burmese)", "Nepali", "Norwegian", "Nyanja (Chichewa)", "Odia (Oriya)", 
        "Oromo", "Pashto", "Persian", "Polish", "Portuguese (Portugal, Brazil)", "Punjabi", "Quechua", "Romanian", "Russian", "Samoan", "Sanskrit", "Scots Gaelic", "Sepedi", "Serbian",
        "Sesotho", "Shona", "Sindhi", "Sinhala (Sinhalese)", "Slovak", "Slovenian", "Somali", "Spanish", "Sundanese", "Swahili", "Swedish", "Tagalog (Filipino)", "Tajik", "Tamil", "Tatar",
        "Telugu", "Thai", "Tigrinya", "Tsonga", "Turkish", "Turkmen", "Twi (Akan)", "Ukrainian", "Urdu", "Uyghur", "Uzbek", "Vietnamese", "Welsh", "Xhosa", "Yiddish", "Yoruba", "Zulu"];

        const value = ["af", "sq", "am", "ar", "hy", "as", "ay", "az", "bm", "eu", "be", "bn", "bho", "bs", "bg", "ca", "ceb", "zh", "zh-TW (BCP-47)", "co", "hr", "cs", "da", "dv", "doi", "nl",
        "en", "eo", "et", "ee", "fil", "fi", "fr", "fy", "gl", "ka", "de", "el", "gn", "gu", "ht", "ha", "haw", "he", "hi", "hmn", "hu", "is", "ig", "ilo", "id", "ga", "it", "ja", "jv", "kn",
        "kk", "km", "rw", "gom", "ko", "kri", "ku", "ckb", "ky", "lo", "la", "lv", "ln", "lt", "lg", "lb", "mk", "mai", "mg", "ms", "ml", "mt", "mi", "mr", "mni-Mtei", "lus", "mn", "my", "ne",
        "no", "ny", "or", "om", "ps", "fa", "pl", "pt", "pa", "qu", "ro", "ru", "sm", "sa", "gd", "nso", "sr", "st", "sn", "sd", "si", "sk", "sl", "so", "es", "su", "sw", "sv", "tl", "tg", "ta",
        "tt", "te", "th", "ti", "ts", "tr", "tk", "ak", "uk", "ur", "ug", "uz", "vi", "cy", "xh", "yi", "yo", "zu"]; 
        
        let selectRef1 = document.querySelector("#from");
        let selectRef2 = document.querySelector("#to");

        for(let i = 0; i < land.length; i++){
            let optionRef = document.createElement("option");
            let optionRef2 = document.createElement("option");
            optionRef.text = land[i];
            optionRef.setAttribute("value", value[i]);
            optionRef2.text = land[i];
            optionRef2.setAttribute("value", value[i]);
            selectRef1.add(optionRef);
            selectRef2.add(optionRef2);
        }
    }
```

I wonder if anyone knows if the Google translation API has an endpoint for getting every language and there value instead of using the two arrays like I've done?

I couldn't find anything about it myself.

Comment: It's nice to mention that you didn't find anything, but what exactly did you try and where did you look? That should be part of the question. Also, there a couple of grammatical mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can send a `GET` request to `https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/languages`

Read more here: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v2/languages